# Eclipse, Gerrit, & left trailing white spaces

Tags: eclipse, whitespace, gerrit, removing-whitespace

Eclipse 4.6.1

CentOS 7

Got a large project with Java and Python files.

There is something about the way I type that leaves blank lines composed of left trailing white spaces before a return.

When I push my code up to Gerrit these show up as angry red rectangles.

I found settings to clean up ALL such left trailing white space upon saving, but I can't really use it, as I often edit existing files that also have such left trailing white spaces in it.  If those get cleaned out to, more lines than those actually altered show in the Gerrit code diff, getting everyone confused.

I've had luck REDUCING this problem by having Eclipse display the special characters.  However, I still miss many because those special character displays aren't very visually promiment --- not like those angry red bars in the Gerrit code diff.

Is there some way I can get the left trailing white spaces in Eclipse to be displayed in a more graphically prominent way?   Is there a way to preview my files in Gerrit without them counting as a patch set?

Comment: Maybe screenshots would clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with this is to use a pre-commit hook that will removing trailing whitespaces and expand tabs in the changed code. We use this one: https://gist.github.com/mokagio/0fbf7d475c9326e30edd